# Taking image with Color blob detector Opencv

Tags: android, opencv

Is there a possible way to take a picture of the displayed image using opencv with the output of the algorithm? Like [this](https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/BKjv) but this method is made with the use of screenshot (powr + vol dwn) which is not efficient.

I wanted to include the Color blob detection's output.  I have done the screenshot method but the problem is that it is always black probably because the method of getting the image in opencv is different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you just want the main image and not the header menu bars etc.

If this is correct and if you are using or building on the ColorBlobDetection example in OpenCV then you actually already have the image you need, I think, in the output of the 'onCameraFrame' method of ColorBlobDetectionActivity - i.e. the mRgba matrix returned.

You should be able to save it or store it using imwrite.

Here is example code which is tested and works - in practice you probably don't want to do this on every frame and instead do it once when some trigger is set, but the code below give the general idea:

```js
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

        if (mIsColorSelected) {
            mDetector.process(mRgba);
            List<MatOfPoint> contours = mDetector.getContours();
            Log.e(TAG, "Contours count: " + contours.size());
            Imgproc.drawContours(mRgba, contours, -1, CONTOUR_COLOR);

            Mat colorLabel = mRgba.submat(4, 68, 4, 68);
            colorLabel.setTo(mBlobColorRgba);

            Mat spectrumLabel = mRgba.submat(4, 4 + mSpectrum.rows(), 70, 70 + mSpectrum.cols());
            mSpectrum.copyTo(spectrumLabel);

            File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String testFilename = "TestOCVwrite.png";
            File testFile = new File(path, testFilename);
            String testFullfileName = testFile.toString();
            Log.i(TAG, "Writing to filename: " + testFilename);
            Boolean writeResult = Imgcodecs.imwrite(testFullfileName, mRgba);
            if (!writeResult) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Failed to write to filename: " + testFilename);
            }
        }

        return mRgba;
    }
```

Some things to watch out for:

Make sure you include the permission to write to external in your manifest:

```js
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

You need to also make sure you include a file type in the file name, such as png, jpeg etc or else you will get the error:

> could not find a writer for the specified extension in function bool cv::imwrite_(const cv::String&, const cv::Mat&, const std::vector&, bool)